# hide components in app.js when a user is not logged in React

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an application in react, I have a login page, and other pages that need the user to be logged in to access.

in my app.js

I have a whole structure that I created with components.

```
  render() {

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>

        <Header showNavLeft={this.state.showNavLeft} onClickBars={(value) => this.setState({ showNavLeft: value })} />
        <Container>
          <NavLeft showNavLeft={this.state.showNavLeft} />
          <Screen>
            <Routes />
          </Screen>
        </Container>


        <GlobalStyle />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

And I have the following route file

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated() ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );

const Routes = () => (

    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={home} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/users" component={users} 
    </Switch>
)
```

When I access the login page, I don't want all of my Header, NavLeft, Container components to be loaded.

What is the best way to validate this?

I'm stuck in this situation, I can't think of how to get around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip it around so that `Routes` is higher up the hierarchy, and the `Header` and `navLeft` components are a separate part of a `Wrapper` component.

```
const Wrapper = ({children} => (
<>
  <Header showNavLeft={this.state.showNavLeft} onClickBars={(value) => this.setState({ showNavLeft: value })} />
      <Container>
        <NavLeft showNavLeft={this.state.showNavLeft} />
          <Screen>
            {children}      
          </Screen>
      </Container>
<GlobalStyle />
</>
```

Then you want to put the Wrapper as the component prop on your Route, and then the home compnent should be a child of it, like:

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/">
  <Login/>
</Route>
<Route path="/home" component={Wrapper}>
  <home/>
</Route>
<Route path="/user" component={Wrapper}>
  <Users />
</Route>
</Switch>
```

Or:

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/">
  <Login/>
</Route>
<Route path="/home" component={Wrapper}>
  <Wrapper>
    <home/>
  </Wrapper>
</Route>
<Route path="/user">
  <Wrapper>
    <Users />
  </Wrapper>
</Route>
</Switch>
```

It might also be easier if you refactor to get rid of the separate PrivateRouter, but have everything in one place, then re-jig things so that the header and navbar are how you like, and then you can see what you want to split out later.

Comment: Thanks for having answered, apparently if I add all the components inside PrivateRoute the problem solves, but the codes will be well repeated, and I will have a problem with my state show variables.

Comment: If you collect all those components up into a `wrapper` component then you wont be repeating code as much.
You might still want to refactor your routes though as they will only get more complex as time goes on

Comment: Your method worked, however, when I use the private route function, it does not work

Comment: or do you have another suggestion for me to work with privateroute? leave, for example, validation within each component?

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand? As you've said, you can continue using your current layout with your PrivateRoute component, but you'll need to duplicate some code. Or you can clean it up a bit and not duplicate your code?

Comment: When using the wrapper the privateroute stopped working, what I did then, was to do the validation inside the wrapper, and now it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So The easiest way is by Taking the Header , Container & NavLeft components from where it is now and moving it to inside PrivateRoute wrapping the component returned in isAuthenticated.

So that it shows up only in Private routes.

Comment: The problem is that there is no component header and navigation for example, I use a variable, which I pass by parameter in app.js

Comment: You could change these to seperate components and call it like i said . and pass down these variables from app.js to Routes component and and to PrivateRoutes and finally to these componets (Header , Container & NavLeft ) which are now inside PrivateRoute.